# What is the `$` 's meaning in this code?

Tags: javascript

Here is partly code,I got confused about the `$` 's meaning.

```
function playSound(e) {
     const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
     const key = document.querySelector('.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
     ...
}
```

I know the first code will return the first element `<audio>` which has `data-key="..."` .But I don't understand the `$`'s function and how to find it.So is there a document to explain it or anything else can help me understand it?

Comment: I think that `$` is a counter.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Javasctipt only.This is the partly code from  javascript30 challenge first stage.

Comment: @T.J Crowder I don't konw how to reply you at this.Sorry about that and I will take care next time.And this question has been solved.Thanks all answers.It is the Template literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can assume you are taking the Javascript30 challenge. As this code is from the first level there.

Here `${}` is a special ES6 string interpolation. To use this you have to use backticks. ( Here $ does NOT mean jQuery. )

For example : The same thing above can be written as :

```
const key = document.querySelector('.key[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
```

Hence, instead of using the `+` sign for the variables, it is much easier and better to use the `${}` for the string interpolation for the variables. Makes the code much easier to understand. Please note that you need to use backticks to 
let the interpolation work.

Comment: so it is not supported in IE

Comment: You are right,I try to  see  the javascript30 video and got stuck this and could not overcome it.

Comment: @Mahi: The ${} is supported in IE Edge.

Comment: @SankalpSingha: Pedantically, Edge != IE. IE ended with IE11. Edge is Edge.

Comment: @LilySun: I hope I was able to help. If you understood the answer then please accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it!  It is Template literals.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.